# Memory leak using WCF GetCallbackChannel over named pipe

Tags: wcf

We have a simple wpf application that connects to a service running on the local machine. We use a named pipe for the connection and then register a callback so that later the service can send updates to the client.

The problem is that with each call of the callback we get a build up of memory in the client application.

This is how the client connects to the service.

```
const string url = "net.pipe://localhost/radal";
_channelFactory = new DuplexChannelFactory<IRadalService>(this, new NetNamedPipeBinding(),url);
```

and then in a threadpool thread we loop doing the following until we are connected

```
var service = _channelFactory.CreateChannel();
service.Register();
```

service.Register looks like this on the server side

```
public void Register()
{
    _callback = OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<IRadalCallback>();
    OperationContext.Current.Channel.Faulted += (sender, args) => Dispose();
    OperationContext.Current.Channel.Closed += (sender, args) => Dispose();
}
```

This callback is stored and when new data arrives we invoke the following on the server side.

```
void Sensors_OnSensorReading(object sender, SensorReadingEventArgs e)
{
    _callback.OnReadingReceived(e.SensorId, e.Count);
}
```

Where the parameters are an int and a double. On the client this is handled as follows.

```
public void OnReadingReceived(int sensorId, double count)
{
    _events.Publish(new SensorReadingEvent(sensorId, count));
}
```

But we have found that commenting out _event.Publish... makes no difference to the memory usage. Does anyone see any logical reason why this might be leaking memory. We have used a profiler to track the problem to this point but cannot find what type of object is building up.

Answer (score 1):

Well I can partially answer this now. The problem is partially caused by us trying to be clever and getting the connection to be opened on another thread and then passing it back to the main gui thread. The solution was to not use a thread but instead use a dispatch timer. It does have the downside that the initial data load is now on the GUI thread but we are not loading all that much anyway.

However this was not the entire solution (actually we don't have an entire solution). Once we moved over to a better profiler we found out that the objects building up were timeout handlers so we disabled that feature. That's OK for us as we are running against the localhost always but I can imagine for people working with remote services it would be an issue.